# The Brothers' Riddle

Tags: riddle

Here's another riddle I know from a while back:

> The smallest of its brothers
>
> Twelve of them in all
>
> A large heart in the middle

Comment: A dozen probably could've help mask the fact it was months, versus the number 12. Just a suggestion

Comment: @Insane so could a spoiler tag in your comment...

Comment: @thumbtackthief Can't use spoiler in comments.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe it's

> February

The smallest of its brothers

> Shortest month

Twelve of them in all

> 12 months in a year

A large heart in the middle

> Valentine's Day on the 14th

Answer (score 20):

Here's a viable option though I think @MikeM's answer is probably the intended one

> The first rib

Reasoning

> The first rib is the smallest of the 12 rib bones, and your heart is in the middle of your rib cage

Comment: Wasn't aware of that. This is not the answer either however.

Comment: Very nice answer. I like how it takes the puzzle a bit too literally =D

Comment: Your solution works in societies where Valentine's day is unknown/illegal.

Answer (score 13):

Could it be that what you mean is:

> The Ace of hearts card

Comment: Good guess, but no. Plus there are thirteen cards in a suite which is one too many.

Comment: @dcfyj It could have been read as 12 referring to `its brothers` instead of it plus its brothers. I think it's a good guess if it's the ace of hearts.

Comment: Yes, the ace of hearts is what I meant. But well, it seems this is not the right answer still.

Comment: The Queen probably wouldn't like being called a brother.

Comment: @MikeM. I see you consider numbers to be males :P

Comment: Not at all. I mean, have you gotten a look at 8? I just figured the Queen would be the one most likely to take offense. :-)