# The youngest, What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I'm the shortest of all my brothers and sisters
>
> I've never won first
>
> I'm known to love the water
>
> And I leap with a burst
>
> In the north I like it colder
>
> And I have a heart that can be versed

What am I?

Hint:

> I don't leap far

Edit with @Keeta - reinstate Monica suggestion

Comment: Reminds me of [this riddle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32931/the-brothers-riddle) that I posted a few months ago. (No I'm not considering your's to be a duplicate, just a very clever re-imagining)

Comment: Does the underscore in your name happen to represent a D?

Comment: Maybe you should finish it into a six line poem with something like "And my heart is often versed." or "Yes cold, but not the worst."

Comment: I have a suggestion >The weather factor should be removed as it doesn't apply to everyone. Southern Hemispheric countries have their summer in December, January and February, therefore 'I also like it colder' will make it almost impossible for the riddle to be solved down there.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you are

> February

I'm the shortest of all my brothers and sisters

> February is the shortest month of the year.

I've never won first

> It's also the second month.

I'm known to love the water

> In astrology, the star signs Aquarius and Pisces overlap in February - both water signs.

And I leap with a burst

> Every four years an extra day gets added for a leap year.

I also like it colder

> February is usually counted as being at the end of Winter/beginning of Spring so is a bit colder (in the Northern hemisphere at least).

Title

> February was one of the last months to be added to the Roman calendar

Comment: (Trying to phrase this without giving anything away...) I'm not sure if it's the last one added, but it's the last one in their cycle. (That is, theirs started two after ours.)

Comment: Yup yup! Correct

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> Oxygen?

I'm the shortest of all my brothers and sisters

> I guess it's rather light / small / whatever

I've never won first

> Second common atom (after Iron (FE))

I'm known to love the water

> H2O as common join

And I leap with a burst

> Big blast when ignited

I also like it colder

> Probably something I missed out in chemistry classes

As for the title:

> I can't find a match there, since it was probably discovered early

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. This is a really good answer. Trying adding smallest chalogen( to second hint), and for 'colder' look for cryogenic plants.

Answer (score 3):

Are you...

> An icicle?

I'm the shortest of all my brothers and sisters

> Icicles are different lengths.

I've never won first

> The shortest icicle will be the last to fall.

I'm known to love the water

> It's made of it!

And I leap with a burst

> When icicles fall, they certainly burst

I also like it colder

> Icicle wouldn't exist if it wasn't cold

Spoiler

> Basically falls straight down.